# How do you recover previous versions of a file without git?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My friend who uses Visual Studio Code accidentally deleted most of his code and saved the file. He does not have git running yet since he reset his computer recently and we were wondering - is there a way to recover the old version of the file?

Comment: you need to use an incremental backup tool that makes copies every X minutes, X hours,..... Or a version system like VMS

Answer (score 0):

If you have by any chance deleted a file itself:

there is a piriform program called 'recuva', If you know the file location and the filename there is great chances to recover it.

If you have version enabled for the file(windows): right click on the file, properties and then 'previous versions' tab.

Anyways those times reveals git not as a best pratice, but as essencial dev tools nowadays!!!